# Hex Array cout to text file failure

Tags: c++, windows, file, printf

Hi I have been trying to get my code to output results to a text file without any luck. I'll greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look at it for me.
I tried `fstream` and `cout` without any luck... eventually I just used batch `file.exe > Out.txt` to out put the result. Is there anyway to do this in the cpp code without pulling my hair out?

This is my current code it should output... what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int hex_to_int(char c)
{
    if (c >= 97)
        c = c - 32;
    int first = c / 16 - 3;
    int second = c % 16;
    int result = first * 10 + second;
    if (result > 9) result--;
    return result;
}

int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d){
        int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
        int low = hex_to_int(d);
        return high+low;
}

int main(){

   std::string line,text;
   std::ifstream in("Input.txt");
   while(std::getline(in, line))
   {
       text += line ;
   }
        const char* st = text.c_str();
        int length = strlen(st);
        int i;
        char buf = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
                if(i % 2 != 0){


                std::ofstream out("Output.txt");
                std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save old buf
                std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to Output.txt CrickeyMoses!
                printf("%c", hex_to_ascii(buf, st[i]));
                std::cout << std::flush;
                std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
                }else{
                        buf = st[i];                          
                }
        }
}
```

Input.txt:

```
2b524553503a4754494e462c3046303130362c3836323139333032303637373338312c2c34312c38393135343530303030303030343333353631322c33312c302c312c302c2c342e312c302c302c2c2c32303137313031323231353932332c2c2c2c30302c30302c2b303030302c302c32303137313031323232303032322c3534344324
0A
2b524553503a4754494e462c3046303130362c3836323139333032303637373338312c2c34312c38393135343530303030303030343333353631322c33312c302c312c302c2c342e312c302c302c2c2c32303137313031323231353932332c2c2c2c30302c30302c2b303030302c302c32303137313031323232303032322c3534344324
```

Output.txt:

```
+RESP:GTINF,0F0106,862193020677381,,41,89154500000004335612,31,0,1,0,,4.1,0,0,,,20171012215923,,,,00,00,+0000,0,20171012220022,544C$
+RESP:GTINF,0F0106,862193020677381,,41,89154500000004335612,31,0,1,0,,4.1,0,0,,,20171012215923,,,,00,00,+0000,0,20171012220022,544C$
```

Hex to ASCII C++ decoder

Comment: What's wrong with using the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) I/O manipulator for scanning writing?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother redirecting `std::cout`. It seems you wanted to do this so you could format the return value as characters with `printf`. This can be done by just casting it to `char` and then outputting directly to the `std::ofstream`.

```
std::ofstream out("Output.txt", std::ios::out);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if (i % 2 != 0){
        out << static_cast<char>(hex_to_ascii(buf, st[i]));
    } else {
        buf = st[i];
    }
}

out.close();
```